# Continue moving in the same direction as the last input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on my spaceship game. I have done a lot of things in it but now I am facing a problem. The controls of the game are made by `Input.GetAxis`.

What I want to do now is that once I take the thinger of the W key, for the player to continue move in the same direction or from others keys. I want the player to continue moving in the same direction as the last input and if the gamer will want to change its direction he will need to click on another button, and *then* it will start moving in another direction. I tried it by myself but I didn't succeed.

```
public float Force;
public Rigidbody rb;
public float speed;
public Done_Boundary boundary;
public float RotSpeed;
public GameObject shot;
public Transform shotSpawn;
public float fireRate;
private float nextFire;
/*public Text bullettext;
public int maxbullet = 35;
public int curbullet = 0;
public GameObject NoBulletP;
public bool bulletgiving = false;
public void OK()
{
    NoBulletP.SetActive (false);
}*/
void Start()
{
    //curbullet = maxbullet;
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();

}
void Update ()
{
    //bullettext.text = "Bullets: " + curbullet;
    if (Input.GetButton ("Fire1") && Time.time > nextFire)
    {
            /*if (curbullet == 0) 
            {
                NoBulletP.SetActive (true);
               if(!bulletgiving)
              {
                  StartCoroutine (wait());
              }
            }
            else if(curbullet > 0)
            {
            curbullet--;*/
            Instantiate (shot, shotSpawn.position, shotSpawn.rotation);
            nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;
            GetComponent<AudioSource> ().Play ();
            /*}
           else if(curbullet < 0)
           {
            curbullet = 0;
           }*/
    } 
}
void FixedUpdate ()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");
    rb.velocity = transform.forward * moveVertical * speed;
    transform.Rotate (0.0f,moveHorizontal * RotSpeed * Time.deltaTime,0.0f);
    rb.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp (rb.position.x, boundary.xMin, boundary.xMax), 0.0f, Mathf.Clamp (rb.position.z, boundary.zMin, boundary.zMax));
}
```

Comment: `please don't pay attention to the coment that is some old stuff` it'd be ideal if you only posted relevant code in the future.

Comment: ok thanks but can you help me now I will learn on my mistakes I am new on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because `Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")` and `Input.GetAxis("Vertical")` gets a value of 0 when the key is not being pressed.

Change the the code in `FixedUpdate()` to this:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = 0f;

    if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") != 0f) 
    {
        moveVertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        rb.velocity = transform.forward * moveVertical * speed;
    }

    transform.Rotate(0.0f, moveHorizontal * RotSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f);
    rb.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(rb.position.x, boundary.xMin, boundary.xMax), 0.0f, Mathf.Clamp(rb.position.z, boundary.zMin, boundary.zMax));
    rb.AddForce(transform.forward * Force);
}
```

I'm using `GetAxisRaw` because it gives a value of -1 or 1 when is pressed and 0 when its not.

Comment: it says that I am using an unsigned float

Comment: that foat is movevertical

Comment: Assets/Done_Scripts/Done_PlayerController.cs(69,51): error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable `moveVertical'

Comment: declare `moveVertical` like this `float moveVertical = 0f;`

Comment: so I tried and now it is moving just how it moved in the beginning , when I take my finger of it stops moving

Comment: but it need to continue moving and when I click another button it needs to stop and start the other one

Comment: I changed the code in the answer, I think that should work.